# change color of item of clicable customList

Tags: android, custom-lists

I am developing android application and its related mail box and I want to do separete  read and unread message from each other.I am tyring this.When Clicked item in CustomListView save item positon or name and change color of textView which clicked in CustomListView and When Refresh activity get changed color which clicked

```
package com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRefreshListener,
        OnClickListener {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    JSONArray jsonarray2;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FLAG = "flag";

    Button btngeri;

    static Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.enveloppe, R.drawable.enveloppe,
            R.drawable.enveloppe, R.drawable.enveloppe, R.drawable.enveloppe,
            R.drawable.enveloppe, R.drawable.enveloppe };

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        btngeri = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_geri);
        btngeri.setOnClickListener(this);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Mail Kutusu");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Güncelleme Yapılıyor...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            JSONObject returndata = null;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://78.186.62.169:8210/AnketServis.asmx/Message");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            JSONObject jsonparameter = new JSONObject();

            try {

                // jsonparameter.put("AnketID", "3");

                httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonparameter.toString(),
                        "UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                Log.i("@banner_responseString", "" + responseString);

                try {
                    returndata = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = returndata.optJSONArray("d");
                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();
                    Log.i("@lengthJson", "" + lengthJsonArr);
                    int sorusayisi = lengthJsonArr;

                    for (int i = 0; i < sorusayisi; i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                        if (i == sorusayisi)
                            break;
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode
                                .getJSONObject(i);

                        map.put("message", jsonChildNode.getString("ID"));
                        map.put("country", jsonChildNode.getString("Konu"));
                        map.put("rank", jsonChildNode.getString("Tarih"));
                        map.put("population", jsonChildNode.getString("Mesaj"));
                        // map.put("population", datetime);
                        // map.put("population",
                        // jsonobject.getString("population"));
                        // map.put("flag",
                        // jsonChildNode.getString("Tarih"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist, imageId);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

}
```

ListView Adapter

```
// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
private final Integer[] imageId;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist, Integer[] imageId) {

    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    // rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
    country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
    // population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            // intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
            // Pass all data population
            // intent.putExtra("population",
            // resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
            // Pass all data flag
            intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return itemView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Use Selectors to give a responsive touch to your Layout. Just Research about selectors . I am Sure You'll Find Something.

Answer (score 0):

bg.xml

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
   </shape>
```

itesm_select.xml

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg"/>
    </selector>
```

listview

```
       <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:saveEnabled="true"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/itesm_select"
            />
```